# Excel, using array in averageifs formula

Tags: excel, average, array-formulas

I am attempting to use an array formula with multiple criteria in an AVERAGEIFS formula.

=AVERAGEIFS('sheet1'!$R:$R,'sheet1'!$B:$B,{"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"},'sheet1'!$A:$A,Q$2)

The formula only seems to be calculating the first criteria that is within the array ("a").

I searched the forums, but I am not seeing anything that directly relates to this this.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This works! Thank you Brad!

Answer (score 2):

The trick when using an array inside something like `AVERAGEIFS` is to then wrap it in `AVERAGE`. However, this will take the average of the averages which is probably not what you want. This method however does work well with Counts and Sums from which you can make your own average.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(SumRange,CriteriaRange,{"a","b","c"}))/SUM(COUNTIFS(CriteriaRange,{"a","b","c"}))
```

This will be the same answer as if you had used `Average(<select only the cells with "a", "b", "c" values>)`

And to elaborate on how the `Average(AverageIfs())` process works you can see the difference when you Evaluate your formula

[image]
[image]
[image]

There `AverageIfs` only regarded the first argument of the array.

However when it is returning a value to another function which itself can take an array as an argument the array is preserved

[image]
[image]